# Finding missing Invoice in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I will first explain the current procedure : 
My Client sends Invoices to the Customers every month. There are around 5000+ customers to whom the invoices are sent.

Now My client wants me to find out the customers for which he did not send the invoice in a particular month.(Say in the month of May 2016)

I think saved search will do the task. I tried but with no genuine results.

Thanks in Advance
Gladiator

Comment: How do you know if an invoice was sent? If it exists?

Comment: There is a column which mentions the date when the invoice was sent. and there is another column which mentions the corresponding invoice no. when clicked on the Invoice number all the details for the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

You need a transaction saved search where the 'sent' field (or whatever your field is called) is empty. If you can't get the right results, try the 'expression' option for a saved search. This lets you easily negate search criteria, so you can fine-tune what your search returns.

Answer (score 0):

I will base my answer from your comment below.

> There is a column which mentions the date when the invoice was sent. and there is another column which mentions the corresponding invoice no. when clicked on the Invoice number all the details for the invoice. – Galdiator May 16 at 12:57

Create a saved search that will look for invoice with following filters (AND logic):

- Its date field (date when the invoice was sent) is within this month AND
- Invoice number (field for corresponding invoice no) is null/empty AND
- Sent by your customer. *****(This is something you need to add on the invoice form and include it on whatever automation you are using to set the date field and invoice number.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a saved search on the Invoice, with the required date criteria's and an additional criteria for "Messages : Date is empty" .

You might have to group your results based on the document number.

The above criteria along with your month/date range criteria will give you all the Invoices which does not have any email under the communication -> Messages tab.

Hope this works for you.